# How to stream first 5 tweets? And how to stream only those users enabled geographic info and real name?

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

I am trying to use tweepy to stream some specific data, I read the tweepy documentation but wasn't helping. I would like to do the followings:

1. Printout only the first 5 tweets, then stop the script. I tried
   to use a "for" loop, but it keeps streaming.
2. I would like to stream only those tweets on a specific topic (ie: car) for those
   Twitter users who i) have enabled the geographic info and ii) used
   real name as an username.
3. Export and append the streamed tweets into a csv file

Any directions as to how I can learn or approach this will be greatly appreciated.

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import sys

ckey = ""
csecret = ""
atoken = ""
asecret = ""

class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True
    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

counter = 0
for counter in range (0, 5):
    counter += 1
    auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
    auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
    twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
    twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
```

Edited version:

```
import tweepy
import time

ckey = ""
csecret = ""
atoken = ""
asecret = ""

OAUTH_KEYS = {'consumer_key':ckey, 'consumer_secret':csecret,
    'access_token_key':atoken, 'access_token_secret':asecret}
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_key'], OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_secret'])
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='car', since='2014-09-01', until='2014-09-02').items(5):
    if tweet.geo != None:
        print tweet.geo, tweet.author.screen_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script I use. Much simpler than what you had, in my opinion.
I am not sure someone can use their name as a user name, wouldn't it be their name without spaces?

You can limit the tweets using "items" before you retrieve the tweets. If you want the first 5, you would not be able to know in advance how many people added their location, so I would probably get more than 5 tweets just in case.
If you don't want to restrict the number of tweets, leave items empty.

```
import tweepy
import time
OAUTH_KEYS = { 'consumer_key':your key, 'consumer_secret':your secret, 'access_token_key':your token, 'access_token_secret':your token secret }
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_key'], OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_secret'])
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_KEYS['access_token_key'], OAUTH_KEYS['access_token_secret'])
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q='car', since='2014-09-01', until='2014-09-02').items(5):
if tweet.geo != None:
    print tweet.geo, tweet.author.screen_name
```

You can easily find documenation on how to append to csv.

Comment: Thanks but the outputs look something like this: <tweepy.models.Status object at 0x02878430><tweepy.models.Status object at 0x02878450><tweepy.models.Status object at 0x02878570>... etc. When I replaced "print tweet" by "print tweet.user.screen_name" it shows the screen name. I wonder if can I find (i.e. a documentation?) all the sub-functions available for the Status object?

Comment: Another question, your suggested line here "since='2014-09-01', until='2014-09-02'", does it mean my outcomes come from a historical data? I didn't know we can get historical data from Twitter's free API.

Comment: And sorry I am new, just one more question. I replace "print tweet" with "print tweet.geo", it prints "None" 5 times, which is strange because I thought the condition "if tweet.geo != "None":" should filter out all tweets with geo == None.

Comment: oh, yeah, remove the quotes from None. Sorry about that.

Comment: I saved for myself some key attributes that you can access using the cursor object:  
text,
author.screen_name,
author.name
author.location
author.time_zone,
author.geo_enabled,
author.friends_count,
source,
geo,

Comment: I removed the quotes (see edited version above), but it doesn't print out anything now. Now sure why?

Comment: Also, if I would like to learn more about the key attributes, where can I go to? I have searched through the tweepy documentation (http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v2.3.0/index.html), but it doesn't mentioned the attributes you mentioned.

Comment: I think I know why now. Since none of the first 5 tweets contained users who enabled the geo-info, so that returns None. So I guess it's not possible just to request to stream geo-enabled tweets, I have to stream everything related to a keywords, then filter out the ones that don't have geo-enabled.

Comment: Just one more bug to fix (in addition to my other follow-up questions above): I set the item to be 200 and it shows the right name and geo info, but at one point, it crashes with this "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u270c' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)", I encountered this in my other twitter-unrelated scripts, and what I did was to tell python to ignore weird characters using .encode("ascii", "ignore"), but it didn't work on your script (I tried: tweet_encode = tweet.encode("ascii", "ignore")...